# When creating an application, when should I use the map satellite view instead of the plain one?

Tags: mobile-application, maps

From UX Perspective, If I create a map-based mobile application why should I not use the map satellite view instead of the vector one?

Is it because it is crowded with data and the user will not be able to distinguish the roads as easily, or is there another reason that it has to do with the performance?

Comment: This site is not suitable for having "discussions". You should ask a specific question that can be answered directly. Unfortunately, a question about why Uber made a specific design decision is something that we can't answer, you would have to ask the person at Uber who made the decision.

Comment: Perhaps you could salvage your question by removing any references to Uber, and instead ask a question about why a simple map might be preferred over a more complex and detailed map.

Comment: You have a point, thank you for sharing your insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At 1st this might seem logical. but imagine a dense area with many buildings and overhead structures, or an area with a lot of trees and foliage. Also consider the underground parts of certain roads and highways. There's too many factors. This would make it hard to actually see the road. Instead in the vector based map is much easier to isolate the road from all the other details

Comment: Not worth adding a whole new answer for this, but a satellite photo requires a lot more data to display than the symbolic vector representation. In areas with poor service, this could render the app unusable. For users without unlimited data plans, this could be a deterrent.

Comment: @Ameen thank you for your answer, I am worried about the performance as well as the crowded look, that is why i posted such question.
My client insists on using it despite all the logical reasons for not doing so.

Comment: @FatmaHegazy Perhaps suggest that this be provided as an option rather than the unchangeable default.

Comment: @maxathousand You are absolutely right, I will suggest that for sure.